# Why does my model look this weird?

Tags: 3d-view

My units are mm - meters. Why Am I not seeing my model completely solid?

[image]

[image]

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your screenshot in the right panel the camera far plane clipping is set to 1000km which is far to high. set it to somewhat around 10m to 1km depending on what you need